# Referencing secondary manifests in dash

Tags: mpeg-dash, aws-media-convert, aws-mediatailor

I am currently exploring SSAI implementation via mediatailor. From the looks of it, by default mediatailor requires the entire VMAP response at the start. I am looking for a way (in VOD) where I can defer which the decision of which ad needs to be player till the cue-point is reached. I want to check if there is a way to reference a dash manifest from my current manifest i.e. if there is a possibility of having nested dash manifests so that I can add a reference to manifest link which will be created at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

At present no AWS services support nested DASH manifests.

Regarding the delayed ADS query for a VOD manifest, what you described is how many client-side ad insertion systems work.  You might achieve your goal with a CSAI solution or a hybrid of SSAI and CSAI.